# Injectivity of pushout in the category of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Let $G,H,K$ be groups with $i:K\rightarrow G,j:K\rightarrow H,f:G\rightarrow G *_K H$ and $g:H\rightarrow G *_K H$ such that $f\circ i=g\circ j$. I want to prove that if $i$ and $j$ are injective then so is $f$. I first thought about using the universal property, if we manage to find a group $L$ and $\varphi:G\rightarrow L,\psi:H \rightarrow L$ with $\varphi$ injective such that $\varphi\circ i=\psi\circ j$ then by the universal property there would exist $u:G *_K H\rightarrow L$ such that $\varphi=u\circ f$, it would then follow that $f$ is injective. I tried with $L=G*H$ and $\varphi:G\hookrightarrow G*H$ but failed to find a morphism $\psi$ satisfying the commutativity condition. I also tried to use the construction of the pushout in the category of groups, but it led nowhere. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "$\star_K$" mean?

Comment: It's the pushout, namely $G *_K H=(G*H)/N$ where $G*H$ is the free product of $G$ and $H$ and $N$ is the normal subgroup of $G*H$ generated by $\{ i(k)j(k)^{-1}, k\in K\}$.

Comment: This is a nontrivial theorem that requires you to actually know something about what $G*_KH$ looks like (i.e., it's not just abstract nonsense).  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33989/amalgamated-products for instance.

Comment: The answer linked to by Merle is particularly bad, because it pretends there is no issue, when this in fact a non-trivial result.  The answer linked to by Eric Wofsey (and also by the comment to the question linked to by Merle) is slightly better, in that it states what is happening, but does not actually prove anything.  Slightly better again than those is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828828/amalgamated-product Again the main result is not proven, but part of an argument is given, with a textbook reference to complete the argument.  I think the proof is a bit long to

Comment: hope for a complete argument in an answer.  However I remember reading the proof in that textbook reference years ago, and it was not too long or complicated.  By coincidence this question popped into my mind today.  I was trying to remember if there is an easy proof using the diamond lemma, but that only works in the case where $K$ is trivial.  Note the result also gives you that all epimorphisms are surjections, as if $f: G \to H$ is not surjective, you can use $H*_G H$ as the target object, to demonstrate that $f$ is not an epimorphism.

Comment: I agree. My answer was not an answer at all, so I deleted it.

Comment: @Merle I did not intend to criticize your answer.  The answer you linked to did claim to answer the question, so it was legitimate for you bring it to the OP's attention.  It was the answer that you linked to that I claim is bad.