Amalgamated Product Isomorphism
Let $H, G_1, G_2$ be groups such that there exists homomorphisms $f_1:H \to G_1$ and $f_2:H \to G_2$. Furthermore let $H \simeq G_1 *_H G_2$. Does it follow that $H \simeq G_1, G_2$?
I am particularly interested under the circumstances of Seifert-Van Kampen theorem where we have a commutative diagram of fundamental groups. I would assume it is true in this case since $\pi_1(U\cap V) \simeq \pi_1(X)$ should imply that $f_1,f_2$ are injective and the respective inclusions into $\pi_1(X)$ are surjective. But because of the injectivity of $f_1,f_2$ these are also injective and thus $\pi_1(U\cap V) \simeq \pi_1(U), \pi_1(V)$

The question you asked was answered excellently by @DanielCzmmx (+1).  However, the question I think you intended to ask is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33989/amalgamated-products  So if $f_1$ or $f_2$ is not surjective, then we have an element in $G_1 *_H G_2$, which is not in the image of the implied map $H \to G_1 \star_H G_2$, contradicting it being an isomorphism.  Thus $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective.  You have already identified that they are injective.  Thus you have isomorphisms $H\cong G_1, H\cong G_2$.

Actually I think this thread is better: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828828/amalgamated-product?noredirect=1&lq=1  It was closed as a duplicate, but contains good references and a proof, rather than just a statement of the result.

First take some $H$ non-trivial. Now set $G_1=H$ and $G_2=\{1\}$. Also set $f_1,f_2$ to just be trivial maps (sending everything to identity) so that the free product with amalgamation is just the same thing as the free product. Thus $G_1 *_H G_2 \cong H * {\{ 1 \}} \cong H$ but $H \ncong G_2$.
If you wanted to see this play out via Seifert-Van Kampen then imagine the curved surface of a cylinder (e.g. $S^1 \times [0,1]$) with a disc being glued to its side along the boundary of the disc. Take as U and V slightly larger open neighbourhoods of the cylinder and the disc (respectively).

$\pi_1(U) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ ($U$ is homotopic to $S^1$)
$\pi_1(V) \cong \{ 1 \}$ ($V$ is contractible)
$\pi_1(U \cap V) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ ($U \cap V$ is also homotopic to $S^1$)

But since $U \cap V$ is a contractible subset of both $U$ and $V$, the natural maps of $\pi_1(U \cap V)\rightarrow\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(U \cap V)\rightarrow\pi_1(V)$ are both trivial.

...and if $H$ is trivial, then of course the claim is instead true

ok thanks I obviously missed this trivial example. I guess what I really want is more of a Seifert van Kampen case where we know that in particular the inclusion map $f: U\cap V \to X$ is isomorphic on fundamental groups. And then from the commutative nature I think my claim should follow

I'm sorry but I don't understand why your Seifert van Kampen example contradicts what I wrote. So if we have inclusion maps $f:U\cap V \to X$, $f_1:U\cap V \to U$ and $f_2:U\cap V \to V$ and $f_:\pi_1(U\cap V) \to \pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic, shouldn't we then get from SvK that $f_{1}$, $f_{2*}$ are injective as well as the inclusions of $U, V$ into $X$ would be surjective on fundamental groups? But then because $f_1, f_2$ are injective I think one has that $\pi_1(U), \pi_1(V)$ map injectivly into the amalgamated product und thus we have an isomorphism of all four fundamental groups

Just wanted to add that if your counterexample to SvK is with regard to my original question, then I do understand your arguments. My comment is with regard to my other comment

yes that's right, not trying to contradict you, the spaces were just to illustrate how my example could arise from a SVK setting.
